# How to override third party library class' method in android studio?

Tags: android, android-spinner

So I am using a third party library called Multi Selection Spinner. The advantage of this library is we can select multiple names in the spinner. By default we can select only one option.And also searchable feature also in this library.

If i select 5 items in the spinner, after clicking OK button in the alert dialog box it will show all the 5 items in the spinner (As selected). But what I want is i have to show only three names after that etc... should be there.

For this purpose I want to override some methods of this library for my project.

How can I do this(override third party library method locally ) or is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can do this by adding these functions and functions dependencies to your own class then customise the functions with your own requirement. It will behave same like library.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this thing to import module of this library instead of dependencie.

Comment: I don't know how to import module...Can you tell me how to import this library as a module?